# NoT found url to show contents of index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello i need to show the content of index.php for all the not found url, 
For example

```
http://domain.com/random must show http://domain.com/index.php content
http://domain.com/random/random.html must show http://domain.com/index.php content
http://domain.com/random/rand/random.php must show http://domain.com/index.php content
```

I tried below code , but still i get not found error

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*?)/?$ /$1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: answer by icabod is working :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are including part of the requested path in the rewritten URL, by using the `$1`, which effectively inserts the first bracketed part of the rule into the new URL.  This means that your request for `http://domain.com/random/rand/random.php` would try to return the file `http://domain.com/random/index.php`.

In addition, your rule woudn't match your first example, as that URL doesn't contain a `/`, which is required by your regex.

Instead, if the requested URL isn't a file or directory (or link), then just rewrite *everything* to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,R]
```

Note that I've added the `R` flag, which means that the requesting system (the browser) will see that the URL has changed... not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Hi sometime it works well , sometime it keeps on redirecting same page ?